# None of my custom AngularJS directives ever work

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation, directive

I have tried so many examples I found online, like:
http://codepen.io/brunoscopelliti/pen/ECyka

After trying all these examples, not a single one works. I am doing form validation in an HTML form right now. The inbuilt AngularJS directives are working just fine, like checking for the correct email format, password length and so on. The form also submits to the backend. Do you think there is something wrong with how I define my modules? I currently have a module like this:

```
var mainapp = angular.module("AngulaRails", ["ngResource"]);
mainapp.config([
  "$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] =        document.getElementsByName("csrf-token")[0].content;
    return $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = "application/json"; }]);

mainapp.factory...
mainapp.controller
```

(for form submission, and they work!)

and then

```
mainapp.directive
```

No matter what reputable source or online guide I try a directive from, it just does not work. The rest of the form is just fine - the submit button is disabled, and the other inbuilt directives work.

I am using a beta version of AngularJS - 1.3.0.beta-18. It has a convenient `ng-model-options = "{updateOn: 'blur'}"` which works great for updating the field only when I leave it.

EDIT (as per request):
HTML form:

```
  <div><p><input type="text" required id="user_name" ng-model="name" name="tname" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.tname.$error.required">Required</span>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.tname.$error.text">Your name should be text</span></div>

  <div><p><input type="email" required id="user_email" ng-model="email" name="temail" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" value="" placeholder="Email ID"></p>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.temail.$error.required">Required</span>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.temail.$error.email">Not the correct email format</span></div>

  <div><p><input type="password" required id="password" ng-model="password" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="9" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password.$error.required">A password is required</span>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password.$error.minlength">Your password should at least be 3 characters</span>  
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password.$error.maxlength">Your password should be no more than 9 characters</span></div>


<div><p><input type="password" required name="password_confirmation" repeat-password="password" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="9" ng-model="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" value="" placeholder="Re-enter password"></p>
 <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password_confirmation.$error.required">A  password confirmation is required</span>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password_confirmation.$error.minlength">Your password confirmation should at least be 3 characters</span>  
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password_confirmation.$error.maxlength">Your password confirmation should be no more than 9 characters</span></div>
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="SignUpForm.password_confirmation.$error.repeat">Your password confirmation should be the same as your password</span></div>


  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" id="user_submit" name="commit" ng-disabled="SignUpForm.$invalid" value="Sign Up"></p>
</form>

                            </div>
            </div>
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
mainapp.directive("repeatPassword", function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var otherInput = elem.inheritedData("$FormCtrl")[attrs.repeatPassword];

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                if(value === otherInput.$viewValue) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", true);
                    return value;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", false);
            });

            otherInput.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", value === ctrl.$viewValue);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

LATEST UPDATE:
I did find another solution on StackOverflow that worked just right for me (rather than adapting this one). Unfortunately, I cannot find the link anymore, though I have the code in my file. I am pretty sure all difficulties were due to the latest version of AngularJS having many changes.

Comment: What does your HTML and directive look like? Those are what we would need to see.

Comment: Can you set up an SSCCE on jsfiddle or something where we can see your exact problem?

Comment: Hey Zack Argyle, the directive and HTML form code are now displaying correctly. I don't know what SSCCEE is, Explosion Pills, I will wait and see if someone can help me without that if that is ok with you.

Comment: You may be missing an ng-transclude - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Andrew why is ng-transclude necessary, when many directive examples online don't use it, including this one and it seems to be a good source?

Comment: so 'it's not working' means that the link function doesn't execute or there are errors?

Comment: Vadim, it does not execute. I guess that means the link function does not execute? No actual errors in the sense that the form is not crashing and still doing ok, considering the directive is not working.

Comment: Is that extra space in "repeat- password" messing everything up for you?

Comment: Mithon, oh no it is just how the HTML appears and I could not edit it - I have it correctly formattted on my end without an extra space.

Comment: Is your directive in a different file and you're redefining the module in each file?

Comment: Mithon, all my AngularJS code is in a single file - angular-application.js. The module is defined only once, with the variable name called repeatedly for the controller, factory, directive, etc.

Comment: Ok. Just trying to make sure it's not one of those "doh" things.. ;) My last piece of advice then would be to make a jsfiddle so people can fiddle with your stuff and debug it by running it rather than by eyeballing it.